# GPS-GNAT 2006 not working well on Windows 7

Tags: ada, gnat, gnat-gps

I am working on a project developed in ADA on windows xp using GPS-GNAT 2006 and must port it to windows 7 however when trying to upgrade to a newer version of GPS-GNAT (2008+) the ada code throws exceptions, but on the 2006 version it runs but GPS-GNAT 2006 has issues with hitting breakpoints, opening the IDE, the open project button, etc. My question is are there known compatibility issues with Win7 and GPS-GNAT 2006? And what should be the best course of action to get this old code running on windows 7?

Thanks

Comment: It's 2016. I'd suggest downloading Gnat-GPS 2015, or the FSF Gnat compiler from http://getadanow.com/

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes I have considered a newer version however this project is very old legacy code that also interacts with a C++ UI and Access database. I want to take the path of least resistance to getting it functional on windows 7. I may have to modify to many other more parts by updating GPS-GNAT. And I say that with confidence because I did install GPS-GNAT 2008 and the project immediately crashed on execution. However, with GPS-GNAT 2006 the project runs but I get the aforementioned issues.

Comment: I suspect you will find newer versions are less fragile than you have now. Interaction with C++ is certainly improved from my first contact with Gnat, which was probably around 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two things here: the GNAT compiler itself (for which you might be stuck with an older version indeed), and the GPS IDE, which you can upgrade independently of GNAT. As others have suggested, please upgrade to GPL 2015 for GPS, and keep the old compiler.